# Spring Boot Website : How to manage User Login Session through microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, web, microservices, gateway

I would like to create a **website** split by **multiple Web Apps** in Spring Boot.
Each Web App must be independent, with the exception that I would like to **centralize the login** management and keep Users connected through every Apps.

**Example :**

- App1 : Must be public
- App2 : User must be authenticated
- App3 : User must be authenticated

I would like If a user goes to the App2, the website ask him to login. If he goes after that to the App3, I don't want the website asks him to login again.

My first idea was to share Login Sessions between micro-services, but I have read that it' not a good way. Create a **Gateway** seems the best practice.

**So I tried to use these dependencies :**

- For URL redirection : **Spring Cloud**
- For User authentication : **Spring Security**

Spring Security seems not compatible with Spring Cloud so I haven't figured out how to **redirect requests** and to **check user authentication** at the same time.

If anybody could help me please or has an easy sample to show me, I would be grateful :)

Thanks